# How do I use WebStorm for Chrome Extension Development?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-chrome-extension, intellij-idea, webstorm

I just bought WebStorm 5 and so far have been really enjoying its Inspection features. One hitch I've run in to when developing my Chrome extension is that it doesn't recognize the `chrome` variable:

[image: Unresolved variable or type chrome]

Is there a way I can add the `chrome` variable to the Inspector so that it can autocomplete as I type? I'm guessing I would need to add Chromium as an External Library but I'm unsure where to start.

Answer (score 341, accepted):

### First Time Setup

1. Open the `Settings` dialog (`File` > `Settings`)
2. Click `Languages & Frameworks` > `Javascript` > `Libraries`
3. Click `Download`
4. Make sure `TypeScript community stubs` is selected
5. Select `chrome` from the list (you can find it quickly by just typing `chrome`)
6. Click `Download and Install`
7. Click `OK` to close the Settings dialog.

---

Steps 2-6 illustrated below:

[image: Webstorm Screenshot]

---

### In Subsequent Projects

In any subsequent project, you just:

1. Open the `Settings` dialog again (`File` > `Settings`)
2. Click `Languages & Frameworks` > `Javascript` > `Libraries` again
3. Check `chrome-DefinitelyTyped`
4. Click `OK` to close the dialog.

---

Steps 2-4 shown below:

[image: Webstorm screenshot]

Comment: Works just as well in Intellij

Comment: Thanks for this! now, *google-apps-script* and *google.visualization* are available as well.

Comment: Webstorm11 has changed where to find settings completely.

Comment: @tonymiao Really? I have the latest version of WebStorm, and as far as I can tell, the only change is that the `JavaScript` section is now under `Languages & Frameworks`.

Comment: @tonymiao Sorry, you're right. There used to be "Project Settings" and "IDE Settings" sections under a single "Settings" dialog. Now there are separate "Settings" and "Default Settings" dialogs. I updated the answer.

Comment: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14019047/1181911) by @CrazyCoder below is up-to-date.

Comment: An updated answer is needed as IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 doesn't show "chrome" under "TypeScript community stubs". Any idea how to add that?

Comment: It turned out to be a bug in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26160#u=1490671035044

Comment: On mac, the name is not setting but preference. But you can access it using `command+,`

Comment: There's no "chrome" in the list. All I get is .github, scripts and types

Comment: It should probably be noted that WebStorm will need to be restarted.

Comment: @TylerCrompton not anymore though

Comment: @TylerCrompton is right - a restart may be required. The library wasn't in the list after downloading until after a restart. WebStorm 2023.3.3 | Windows 11

Answer (score 50):

**UPDATE 2**:

It's now supported out of the box, see the [complete answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25466708/104891).

[image: Download library]

**UPDATE**:

There is a more complete stub file that can be added as a library to get code completion. It's a part of the Closure Compiler project. Download [chrome_extensions.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/closure-compiler/HEAD/externs/browser/chrome.js).

See also the [feature request for WebStorm](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-3202) to add this library automatically from the IDE.

---

You need to get the JavaScript library for the Chrome API somewhere, or [use a stub to get basic completion](https://github.com/linux-china/chrome_js_api_stub).

Library or a stub [can be configured in WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html).

---

I found the [JSON files with the Extension API](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/api/). One can write a script that will build JS stubs from these JSON files, the stubs can look like the basic version linked on GitHub above, but with the automatic generation they will contain almost complete API and JSDoc comments so that [documentation like here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html) can be viewed directly in the IDE.

JSON => JavaScript object stubs mapping is pretty straightforward in this case and writing this kind of converter should not take more than a day (or several hours for the skilled coder).

If someone goes ahead and implements it, please post the link to the results here.

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea the best. I actually ended up cloning the Chromium Git Repo and added the folder `/chrome/renderer/resources/extensions` which gave me most of what I wanted for Inspection.

Comment: sirlancelot - doesn't work for me ... can you post here some snipper which has auto completition after adding this dir as a library to WebStorm (or IntelliJ) ?

Comment: I downloaded [Chrome Extension](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js) but to get rid of the `Unresolved variable` warning in WebStorm, I had to add the following line to `chrome_extension.js`: `var chrome = {}` and include it as a library in my project.

Comment: There is also a fairly recent (Dec. 2013) vsdoc file at https://code.google.com/p/chrome-api-vsdoc. It has object, method and parameter descriptions (which this TypeScript version lacks). Descriptions are a bit mangled when viewed with Ctrl-Q due to vsdoc using XML for doc annotations, but still readable and usable. Just add the downloaded vsdoc as a custom JS library in Webstorm.

Comment: New URL to chrome_extension.js: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/closure-compiler/master/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm should one day accept json definitions directly to enable autocomplete for the functions defined. Meanwhile, you can use the program at https://github.com/QuickrWorld/jsgen to convert the json files to js to enable auto-complete for the chrome extension APIs.

Answer (score -2):

For writing AppScript, functions and classes such as **DriveApp**, **SpreadsheetApp**, there is a plugin in WebStorm or Intellij called google-app-script.
The installation method is the same as above. On the other hand, you should mark or open the .gs file as JavaScript. (July 2017)