# How can I convince WebStorm that my userscript loads jQuery?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, userscripts

I have a userscript that loads jQuery using the @require directive in the metadata block:

```
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
```

I guess WebStorm doesn't "know" about userscripts, so it has no idea that that, say, `$` is a function that will already be defined by the time I reference it in my userscript.

Can I make WebStorm believe that my file effectively has the contents of `jquery.min.js` inlined at the top of the file, so that it'll stop giving me warnings about `$` being undefined? e.g. can I maybe place a local copy of `jquery.min.js` in a local folder somewhere and tell WebStorm that it can assume all declarations made in that file?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html looks like it.

Comment: @hobbs That sure is it. Thanks, I didn't find that in my searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Thanks to hobbs for his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080084/how-can-i-convince-webstorm-that-my-userscript-loads-jquery?noredirect=1#comment44538933_28080084) - JetBrains has [a documentation page for Configuring JavaScript Libraries](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html).

What I did was:

1. Download the development version of jQuery 2.1.3 (the "official" JetBrains version of jQuery is 2.0.0).
2. Go to Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries.
3. Click Add. In the menu that pops up:

   1. Name it something.
   2. Add (green plus button) the downloaded jquery-2.1.3.js file.
   3. Set Type to Debug.

And now WebStorm believes that my userscript loads jQuery. Hooray!

Comment: 1. `Settings` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `JavaScript` > `Libraries`
2. Click `Download`
3. Change `Official libraries` to `TypeScript community stubs`
4. Select `jquery` & click `Download and Install`
[Adding dependencies in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997468/how-do-i-use-webstorm-for-chrome-extension-development)