# Undue WebStorm warnings when coding Firefox WebExtensions

Tags: javascript, firefox, webstorm, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am making a Firefox WebExtension. Consequently, I use the relevant API, which, it seems, is not known to WebStorm, hence a lot of warnings.

For example, in the following snippet

```
        //make the panel a drop zone
        panel.ondragover = function (τ) {
            τ.preventDefault();
            τ.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
        };
        panel.ondrop     = function (τ) {
            τ.preventDefault();
            τ.stopPropagation();
            var skware        = document.getElementById(
                τ.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
            skware.style.top  = (τ.clientY - skware.mouseOffset.y) + 'px';
            skware.style.left = (τ.clientX - skware.mouseOffset.x ) + 'px';
            put('skwarePos',
                skware.id,
                {'top': skware.style.top, 'left': skware.style.left}
            );
```

things like `.dataTransfer` would be marked as *Unresolved variable*.

No big deal, but, surely, there must be a way to tell WebStrom that I'm using [Firefox WebExtension JavaScript APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API) and that this variable is hence legit.

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997468/how-do-i-use-webstorm-for-chrome-extension-development) regarding extensions on Chrome, and did find a library called *firefox-Definitely typed*, but the squiggly lines remain.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in the question you linked for Chrome?

Comment: I declared the "definitelt typed" libraries for Chrome *and* FF and it seems to get better, possibly due to the fact that said extension started as a Chrome one.

Comment: I declared the "definitelt typed" libraries for Chrome *and* FF and it seems to get better, possibly due to the fact that said extension started as a Chrome one. Now, this code is definitely *not* typed, I mean, it is not supposed to be TypeScript, and now I have some other ennoying warnings such as *Argument type Function is not assignable to parameter type T* : I suppose I still have some way to go before I use Webstrom to its fullest :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to install isn't the `firefox` type definition but `firefox-webext-browser`, in the same way outlined in the [issue for chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997468/how-do-i-use-webstorm-for-chrome-extension-development) you mentioned