# IntelliJ Firefox Web Extensions Development

Tags: javascript, firefox, intellij-idea, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Am learning how to use the Firefox Web Extensions API, and am using IntelliJ.

[image: IDE: underlined JS: browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => { browser.tabs.executeScript(…]

Is there a way to get code completion / suggestions for the API?

I followed the steps in the answer below, but there doesn't seem to be a complete one for Firefox.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25466708/5941389

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firefox WebExtension type stubs were added recently (Nov 2017) under the name `firefox-webext-browser`. The steps in the answer you linked are now valid (relevant changes in bold):

> ## First time setup
>
> 1. Open the `Settings` dialog (`File` > `Settings`)
> 2. Click `Languages & Frameworks` > `Javascript` > `Libraries`
> 3. Click `Download`
> 4. Make sure `TypeScript community stubs` is selected
> 5. Select **`firefox-webext-browser`** from the list (you can find it quickly by just typing `firefox-w`)
> 6. Click `Download and Install`
> 7. Click `OK` to close the Settings dialog.
>
> ## In Subsequent Projects
>
> 1. Open the `Settings` dialog again (`File` > `Settings`)
> 2. Click `Languages & Frameworks` > `Javascript` > `Libraries` again
> 3. Check **`@types/firefox-webext-browser`**
> 4. Click `OK` to close the dialog.