# How to create Google scripts on desktop using WebStorm?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ide, webstorm, clasp

Scripting on google's IDE is a big pain, it's very laggy and it just sucks.

How can I make the google script editor work on my PC?

I tried downloading this [Clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp#login)

Also I added a library from google to javascript.

but when I run it it gives me this error:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
           ^

ReferenceError: SpreadsheetApp is not defined
```

How can I fix this?

What I'm basically trying to do with this script is to send an email based on a bunch of conditions on a google sheets.

Comment: You can't run it.

Comment: I cannot comprehend why this is not possible, would you explain to me why please

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp` is essentially a JavaScript library available only in the online ide. You can't run it locally. You can however run it online from local terminal using `clasp.run`

Comment: Also look into "qunit for gas" for understanding the testing concept (It doesn't work currently)

Answer (score 4):

In order to be able to run an Apps Script project remotely from your local machine, you need to use the [clasp command run](https://github.com/google/clasp#run) as you will be required to also use some kind of authorization (*you will basically need to connect your local project to your remote Apps Script project and verify it is you the one trying to run it*).

[Here is a complete guide on how to use this command](https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/run.md) but just to summarise a bit you basically will need to set up a `Project ID` and create an `OAuth Client ID` to then be able to login using the credentials obtained from it `clasp login --creds creds.json1`.

This is an example of running a function using the command run:

`clasp run 'functionName'`

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `google-apps-script` library to webstorm might also help you out.

Follow the instructions here, but search for "google-apps-script" in the download library modal. Instead of "chrome" which is what this article is about.

[How do I use WebStorm for Chrome Extension Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997468/how-do-i-use-webstorm-for-chrome-extension-development/25466708#25466708)

You'll then be able to create *.gs files. Open them as javascript.