# JavaScript global object browser not defined

Tags: javascript, global-variables, phpstorm

So, there is a possibility of me just being really dumb here, but when I try using JavaScript's `browser` global object, like it is used [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/create), PhpStorm tells me both `browser` and `notifications` are "Unresolved".

[image: Screenshot PhpStorm Browser unresolved]
[image: Screenshot PhpStorm Notifications unresolved]

Can anyone explain me why this is occurring or clear up my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What system are you using? `browser` is usually for Node. Browsers don't have a `browser` variable by default. For browsers, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) might help.

Comment: I assume you would need to install intellisense support for browser extension APIs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997468/how-do-i-use-webstorm-for-chrome-extension-development might be a duplicate.

Comment: @Ouroborus — I'm not sure how documentation for extension APIs helps with PHPStorm not recognising those extensions in its syntax highlighting.

Comment: where does this object come from? There is no such global var in default APIs.

Comment: @Ouroborus also tried it in a node project, which didn't work either. Your hint was useful though

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25466708/2036148 , except the library you need is "firefox-webext-browser".

Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries -> Download -> firefox-webext-browser -> Download and Install -> enable it in the list.

[image: working settings]