# How to develop Chrome extension with WebStorm?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webstorm

There is no code prompt when writing a Chrome extension with WebStorm.
What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Installing `@types/chrome` as suggested in [How do I use WebStorm for Chrome Extension Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997468/how-do-i-use-webstorm-for-chrome-extension-development) should help:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For ManifestV3 I'd suggest using the [official package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) instead. It contains MV2 too, BTW.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I tried adding everything with "chrome" in it yesterday and it still doesn't work. Today, it's ok.Probably need to restart webstorm.You may not believe it, after this method didn't work for me yesterday, I found some other methods and used it for almost a day...This is the method found, but there are some differences in some places. After seeing your screenshots today, I realized that the method I found this is feasible.

Comment: @wOxxOm and how to add it to webstorm? I'm just starting to learn from the official doc and there no package.json in the tutorials projects.

Comment: @usertest, simply download/install the npm package in any local folder and then add it in webstorm preferences for libraries. Refer to the webstorm documentation for more info if necessary.