# Unresolved variable ckeditorInstance PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, ckeditor5

Is there any way how to make PhpStorm recognize what is a `ckeditorInstance` in this context?

```
const ckEditorElement = document.querySelector('.ck-editor__editable');

const ckEditorInstance = ckEditorElement?.ckeditorInstance;
```

Afterwards I try to access for example the `model` property on the instance and it just looks ugly in the code as every property is underlined.

In the dev tools console using `querySelector()` I can find the instance and it shows all of its available properties.

I see a bunch of ckeditor libraries in PhpStorm settings, but I am not sure if and how any of them are usable for what I need. Because just installing something wouldn't help in this case as I might need to typehint it somehow?

Example of what I mean, an issue I encountered before, but got a simple fix from [How do I use WebStorm for Chrome Extension Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997468/how-do-i-use-webstorm-for-chrome-extension-development)

[image: chrome unresolved variable]

I resolved this by doing what is said in the posts accepted answer - which is to install a chrome type JS library in the settings. What I am doing is different obviously, but a similar issue, and maybe there is a fix to this?

Comment: Have you re-tested since correcting that?  Has the behavior changed in any way as a result?  It's not clear to me what specific problem you're trying to describe.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. In my code I have that string as a constant. It does not change the problem which I have is that PHPStorm shows `Unresolved variable ckeditorInstance`. The code works, but then it underlines everything else I access on the instance, too, because it does not know what it is.

Comment: Have you tried using a JSDoc comment to explicitly provide the type of `ckEditorElement` to the IDE?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I am not sure what would be the correct approach to using JSDoc in this case. Defining the type as `HTMLElement` or `Object` doesn't help IDE know what properties does it contain. I added an example in my post for clarification.